# Using sed to remove lines from a txt file

Tags: shell, unix, sed, awk, grep

I have a big text file from which I want to remove some lines that are in another text file. It seems that the `sed` command in Unix shell is a good way to do this. However, I haven't been able to figure out which flags to use for this. .

database.txt:

```
this is line 1
this is line 2
this is line 3
this is line 4
this is line 5
```

lines_to_remove.txt

```
this is line 1
this is line 3
```

what_i_want.txt

```
this is line 2
this is line 4
this is line 5
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`grep` is much better suited than `sed` for this:

```
grep -Fxv -f lines_to_remove.txt database.txt > what_i_really_really_want.txt
```

Comment: Are you sure that command works or is it on my end? I am getting a `grep: Invalid back reference`.

Comment: Your lines_to_remove.txt file must contain some special characters.  Try adding `-F`.  Editing...

Comment: won't work correctly if database.txt has something like `this is line 10`. You should add `-x` to match whole lines.

Answer (score 1):

In `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)' remove.txt database.txt
this is line 2
this is line 4
this is line 5

$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)' remove.txt database.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: +1 for the solution but I recommend you don't use the letter `l` (el) as a variable name as it looks too much like the number `1` (one) and is even indistinguishable in some fonts and so obfuscates your code. Ditto for the letter `O` (oh) vs the number `0` (zero).

Answer (score 1):

I would use `comm` for this:

```
comm -1 <(sort database.txt) <(sort lines_to_remove.txt) > what_i_want.txt
```

The command is much better suited to your needs.

**NOTE**: The `<(commmand)` syntax is a bashism and is therefore much maligned on SO.  It's short hand for the following:

```
sort database.txt > sorted_database.txt
sort lines_to_remove.txt > sorted_lines_to_remove.txt
comm -1 sorted_database.txt sorted_lines_to_remove.txt > what_i_want.txt
```